# Which is better for product level web server: RHEL/Ubuntu Server/Debian/CentOS

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, webserver

We are planning to setup a linux based web hosting solution, which should include an HTTP server, SMTP server, mongoDB and Java. We want to understand which distribution is better for this purpose.

We very care about:

1. Security including antivirus, patch policy etc
2. Performance
3. Stability
4. Commercial support

Thanks,
Green

Answer (score 1):

In reality, provided you use the server version of each software, not a lot of difference. They all fall from the same tree. its when you start adding on the x11 and desktop environments that they start to change preformace wise. (real web servers should not have the X11)

Red Hat has a long respected history, i would go with that.
Also has better security out of the box (with commercial support? dont know where they stand these days)

you would get the best performance out of Gentoo but it took me 6 months to learn that bloody brilliant curse of a distro.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat is the market leader for a reason, has great Java support and (imho) is not really that expensive.

That said, MongoDB is a bit of a novelty and you will not find that in default RHEL. It might be in Ubuntu / Debian, but I don't know about that. If it is, you can probably get commercial support on it through Canonical by using a supported version of Ubuntu.

CentOS is just RHEL without commercial support and significant lag in patching (they have to wait for Red Hat to patch something first and then get it through their own QA).

Comment: MongoDB does appear to be in Ubuntu and most likely Debian, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Centos, however you want commercial support. In which case your best and most expensive option is probably Red Hat.